# Problem with Clear[assoc] as a value in an Association

Tags: bugs, associations, predictive-interface

**Bug introduced in 10.1 or earlier and fixed in 10.3**

---

According to the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html), in order to make sure that a value in an association is not evaluated at initialization, one can use a RuleDelayed. This works fine:

```
Clear[x]
assoc = <| "a" -> x, "b" :> (x = 1;) |>;

{ assoc["a"], assoc["b"]; assoc["a"] }
```

Now, I want to have a key that clears the association if I extract its value. Like this:

```
assoc = <| "clear" :> Clear[assoc] |>;
```

However, any Mathematica expression that is executed after assigning `assoc` clears `assoc` (in Mathematica 10.1). What is going on?

**Edit**

It turns out this is a bug caused by the [Suggestions Bar](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/75284#75284) as pointed out by the user ilian. Turning off the Suggestions Bar in Edit->Preferences->Interface fixed the issue.

Comment: I'm not quite following: Can you give one example of "executing any command" that does this?

Comment: @Praan Try [turning off](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/75284/145) the Suggestions bar.

Comment: @Arnoud Buzing Literally anything. Any Mathematica expression that is executed after assigning `assoc` clears `assoc`.

Comment: @ilian It worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To turn my comment into an answer, this seems to be an evaluation leak coming from the Predictive Interface. I've let the appropriate developers know and they will look into it.

A workaround for now would be to [turn off](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/75284/145) the Suggestions bar.